# Opening connections to multiple databases

Tags: c#, oracle

I want to connect to multiple databases and want to run some query on through those connections, but it's not working.

```
            string source = "10.0.0.0";
            string user = "abc";
            string password="abc";

             DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {


                string source = dt.Rows[i][2].ToString();
                string user = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();
                int password = Convert.ToInt32(user) + 111;

                OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("Data Source =  " + source + ": 1521/rms; User id = " + user + "; Password=" + password + ";");
                conn.Open();

                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(" SELECT SUM(AI_TRN) FROM tr_rtl where DC_DY_BSN = '06-04-2016'and mall like '%" + Mallname.Text + "%' ", conn);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                OracleDataAdapter oda = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
                oda.Fill(dt);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                conn.Close();


                label1.Text = source;



            }

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
```

sorry i have posted the wrong code

Comment: A new DataTable has no rows to loop over.

Comment: Given the update, I now agree with Crowcoder. Unless you are using some other data table with connection information in it, remove the "For" loop and then run the code. This should populate your data table.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably will need to do is iterate through a list of connections and populate one data table with all the results. Here is an example:

```
List<OracleConnections> Connections = new List<OracleConnections>();
DataTable FinalResults = new DataTable();

foreach (var Connection in Connections)
{
   using (Connection)
   {
      DataTable TemporaryTable = new DataTable();
      Connection.Open();
      OracleCommand Command = new OracleCommand("SomeCommandText", Connection);
      OracleDataAdapter Adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(Command);
      Adapter.Fill(TemporaryTable);
      FinalResults.Merge(TemporaryTable);
   }
}
```

This should give you all the results of each database/connection in one final table (Results) or you can do a dataset if it is different columns/data within each connection.

Updated to explain comments listed above.

```
string Source = "10.0.0.0";
string User = "abc";
string Password = "abc";

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
// Remove this or use another reference (different table), you just created the table ^, it has no rows. -> "for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)"
```

Comment: i am realy realy very sorry.actuly i have posted the wrong portion of code.please hav a look on it now.

Comment: See my comment to your post, but this answer still stands are this is what you will want to do if you are using multiple connections (and then attach the "Final Results" to the datagridview at the end of the "foreach" loop instead of the current setup you have.

Comment: See updated answer, please provide more detail or I cannot help you further. (Error message, where it occurs, etc).